# one parameter divergence formulation

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I was reading this article: http://www.cims.nyu.edu/~trogdon/index_files/publications/periodic.pdf

screenshot:
[image]

And it is not clear to me how to write a pde in a divergence form. How can I transform equation (2.1 evolution pde) into the equivalent one parameter divergence formulation? Any hints?